How to git pull rebase when I have deleted files locally?
I'm working on an XCode project, and I want to push my local changes.
However, my local and remote branch had diverged before I made local changes, so I understand that I have to do a 'git pull and rebase local changes onto upstream changes'.

This lets me resolve the conficts on XCode, except it cannot resolve files that I have deleted on purpose locally after my branch had diverged from origin/main. It has to pull first, but the local file it would pull remote changes onto doesn't exist.

I have tried git pull --rebase origin main, then git rm for the deleted files and git add for other changes files in Terminal, but it doesn't let me get past git rebase --continue because there are conflicts with my commits to XCode. I want to stay away from having to do it on Terminal because it crashed the last time.
What should I do? Any comments would be greatly appreciated.

This question is similar to: git: branches diverged; how to proceed?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Was the file meant to be deleted?

If the file was meant to be deleted, then consider the change that was applied on the upstream branch on that file.... Does it mean that the file needs to be brought back to life? Does that change need to be applied on a different place of the project? We don't have enough information to make an informed decision in what to do at this point.

Hello, I have updated the post with much more detail. When XCode tries to pull --rebase, it fails to resolve files that I have deleted locally on purpose, so I cannot proceed with git pull. Thanks!

Got it—I had to quit XCode, then delete a swap file on Terminal to proceed with the rebase. Git push worked this way, but the git merge conflict comments are added to the actual files, so I had to delete them (<<<<<<< HEAD, =======, >>>>>>>) from project.pbxproj and from the source files before the app could function again.

It is helpful to close Xcode when doing a rebase to avoid conflicts of deleted files and do the rebasing in Terminal. Rebasing and merging in main can change the project file structure, and Xcode isn't the most robust IDE.
Once closed, in terminal you can chose to either delete or add the file that's mentioned in the conflict by doing git add/git rm to add or remove the file and then continue the rebase. (git rebase --continue after adding or removing). It sounds like in your description you already got this down, so I wonder if keeping Xcode open is messing with this file and doing the steps with it closed could help.

The error you're getting can happen if you deleted the files locally but did not commit that change yet. After you commit the file deletions on your local branch, you should be able to rebase as you wish. You will still receive a conflict when rebasing that final commit, and you can simply resolve the conflicts in favor of your deletions. You will only need to do this one time and then you can continue the rebase to complete it.

If you've deleted files locally and want to perform a git pull --rebase, you may encounter conflicts because git pull --rebase tries to replay your local commits on top of the remote changes. When local deletions conflict with remote changes (for example, if the remote repository still has those files), Git may struggle to reconcile these changes.
Here’s how to handle this situation step-by-step:
Step 1: Stash or Commit Any Uncommitted Changes
git stash

Step 2: Pull with Rebase and Handle File Deletions
git pull --rebase origin <branch-name>

Step 3: Resolve Conflicts for Deleted Files
git checkout --theirs <path-to-deleted-file>

Step 4: Apply Stashed Changes (if Any)
git stash pop

Step 5: Verify the Final State and Push Changes (if Necessary)
git push origin <branch-name>

